# Chi-squared two sample test for unbinned discrete data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, discrete-data, histogram

I am wandering through the net but I cannot get a precise description of how to solve this simple task.
Two sets of datas

```
count position
1 11
6 12
12 13
23 14
27 15
...
```

and

```
count position
1 11
4 12
9 13
24 14
24 15
...
```

I do not have intervals, all the chi-squared test descriptions are about bins, I just have discrete points.

**How do I test if distribution 1 is the same as the background distribution 2?**
I know it's silly but I think I twisted my thoughts in a way I cannot get out of it without some enlightment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is just a suggestion. In R:

```
> df1
  count position
1     1       11
2     6       12
3    12       13
4    23       14
5    27       15
> df2
  count position
1     1       11
2     4       12
3     9       13
4    24       14
5    24       15

> chisq.test(cbind(df1$count, df2$count))

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  cbind(df1$count, df2$count)
X-squared = 0.6541, df = 4, p-value = 0.9569

Warning message:
In chisq.test(cbind(df1$count, df2$count)) :
  Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Since position is identical in two data frames.

Comment: I suppose this must be a requirement right? R chisq test works only if I have same sets for position (aka if I do not have a count for position X I should virtually write a 0 count).
Am I right?

Comment: and... what should it mean when it says "approximation may be incorrect"?

Comment: You may check help command: "?chisq.test" for detailed documentation and examples. You need to give either a contigency table (here cbind(list1, list2) which makes one table) or 2 lists separately when a contigency table will be created by chisq.test before the test is applied. If there is no count, then 0 should be entered as 'position' needs to be identical for both counts.